# Indian Citizen applying for NewZealand Visa from USA

Tags: visas, new-zealand

I'm just starting to plan a 10 day trip to New Zealand in October and I'm having trouble finding the best way to apply for a visitor visa. 
I'm an Indian Citizen Living near San Francisco, California. Whats the fastest way to apply for the visa from here?

Answer (score 3):

The website of the New Zealand consulate general in Los Angeles refers to [this page from the Washington DC embassy](https://www.mfat.govt.nz/en/countries-and-regions/north-america/united-states-of-america/new-zealand-embassy-washington/visas/) for visa questions. Follow the instructions there.